# Apply SLD to WMS Layer by OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

I want to change SLD of WMS layer. I think everything is well but SLD does not apply to layer.
Here is the code:

```
var SLD = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
'<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"'+
    'xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'+
    'xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">'+
    '<NamedLayer>'+
    '<Name>'+ layer.Name + '</Name>'+
    '<UserStyle>'+
        '<Name>' + layer.Name + '</Name>' +
        '<Title>A small red flag</Title>'+
        '<Abstract>A sample of how to use an SVG based symbolizer</Abstract>'+
        '<FeatureTypeStyle>'+
        '<Rule>'+
            '<Title>Red flag</Title>'+
            '<PointSymbolizer>'+
            '<Graphic>'+
                '<ExternalGraphic>'+
                '<OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="burg02.svg" />'+
                '<Format>image/svg+xml</Format>'+
                '</ExternalGraphic>'+
                '<Size>'+
                '<ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>'+
                '</Size>'+
            '</Graphic>'+
            '</PointSymbolizer>'+
        '</Rule>'+
        '</FeatureTypeStyle>'+
    '</UserStyle>'+
    '</NamedLayer>'+
    '</StyledLayerDescriptor>';

    SLD = encodeURI(SLD);

    var source = layer.WMSLayer.getSource();
    source.updateParams({ STYLES: undefined, SLD_BODY: SLD });
    this.map.render();
```

Comment: what is the name of your layer on the client and the server? do the namespaces match? do you get an image back or an error? does it work if you add a named mark instead of the svg?

Comment: layer name is hazard.
I get 200 response Ok. and nothing happen to layer. I can apply saved SLD by STYLES param but I cannot apply dynamic SLD by this code

Comment: what does "nothing happened to the layer" mean? no map, the default style?

Comment: It mean nothing happen to layer and it remain in default style

Comment: then your name doesn't match the one geoserver is expecting

Comment: what does "your name" mean? layer name?

Comment: I solved the problem